# Symfony form: how to know precisely which field cause an error

Tags: php, forms, symfony, validation, symfony-forms

I have to fix an issue on a Symfony form validation, which is composed of 30 sub-form, each of the sub-form is composed of 3 entities, each of the entities has about 20-25 fields. So this single form contains more than 1800 fields :-(.

At validation, the developper who code this ugly form check it in a single line like this:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    [...]
}
```

And if form is not valid, in twig Template, he only wrote:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

So if I load the form with current values, and submit it without any modification, the validation faild with the same Symfony default message repeted twice:

> This value should not be blank.
>
> This value should not be blank.

But I have no idea of which of the 1800+ fields cause the error, and I didn't found how to ask Symfony for a given error, which is the field which cause it.

How can I know which field has caused the error ?

---

***Edit***: I followed Alexander suggestion and:

```
$errors = $form->getErrors() ;
foreach($errors as $key => $error) {
    var_dump($error);
}
```

Only gives me twice:

```
class Symfony\Component\Form\FormError#1750 (3) {
    protected $messageTemplate => string(31) "This value should not be blank."
    protected $messageParameters => array(0) {}
    protected $messagePluralization => NULL
}
```

No clue on where it happens.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my answer. You need to go trough the form itself like it is done in getErrors().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not answer exactly your question, even if I understand what you want and what you try to do, I will suggest you another (and maybe better) way.

Your error message `This value should not be blank` is ***not*** the Symfony default error message, it is the Doctrine default error message for anotations **`@Assert\NotBlank`**. And of course, you can customize this error message for each field it is used on your entities. Just add in parenthesis your message this way:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime $startDate
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="The start date should not be blank/is mandatory.")
 * @ORM\Column(name="startDate", type="date", nullable = false)
 */
private $startDate;
```

I understand you are working on someone else code, there is lot of entities and fields, but if you take time to replace most of default messages, it can save you a lot of time now and later.

Comment: I found about 180 annotations "NotBlank" without error messages in the code... Finnaly I added for each a message as you suggest with the entity and field name, and Bam ! the errors are now clear (`Penalty: the "Taxes" field is mandatory.`). You saved my week !

Answer (score 2):

Make a foreach on

```
$form
```

see \vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php -> getErrors

example:

```
        foreach ($form as $child) {
            /** @var FormInterface $child */
            if ($child->isSubmitted() && $child->isValid()) {
                continue;
            }

            $iterator = $child->getErrors(true, $flatten);

            if (0 === count($iterator)) {
                continue;
            }
            $child->getName(); // here is the name of field

            if ($flatten) {
                foreach ($iterator as $error) {
                    $errors[] = $error;
                }
            } else {
                $errors[] = $iterator;
            }
            var_dump($errors); // here are the errors of that field
        }
```

Comment: What abount $child->getName() in the loop?

Comment: if you have an empty array, then the loop didn't continue, so you have found the invalid child. try to find out his name with $child->getName()

Answer (score 2):

I found this method long time ago somewhere on the web, and I am using it on the daily basis :)

```
/**
 * @param FormInterface $form
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getErrorsFromForm(FormInterface $form)
{
    $errors = [];

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $template = $error->getMessageTemplate();
        $parameters = $error->getMessageParameters();

        foreach ($parameters as $var => $value) {
            $template = str_replace($var, $value, $template);
        }
        $errors[$key] = $template;
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $childForm) {
        if ($childForm instanceof FormInterface) {
            if ($childErrors = $this->getErrorsFromForm($childForm)) {
                $errors[$childForm->getName()] = $childErrors;
            }
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Maybe it can help you debug errors.

EDIT: this is orignal SO question [Get all errors along with fields the error is connected to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554562/get-all-errors-along-with-fields-the-error-is-connected-to)

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I gave me an array with the error messages, as I had before, but it don't give me **which** field cause the error...

Answer (score 0):

You can use XDEBUG and see what is the error in `$failed` variable.

Answer (score 0):

**For Symfony 4.x+ (may working with lower versions).**

```
// $form = $this->createForm(SomeType::class);
// $form->submit($data);
// if (!$form->isValid()) {
//     var_dump($this->getErrorsFromForm($form));
// }

private function getErrorsFromForm(FormInterface $form, bool $child = false): array
{
    $errors = [];

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
        if ($child) {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        } else {
            $errors[$error->getOrigin()->getName()][] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $childForm) {
        if ($childForm instanceof FormInterface) {
            if ($childErrors = $this->getErrorsFromForm($childForm, true)) {
                $errors[$childForm->getName()] = $childErrors;
            }
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```